# Editing a jQuery plugin for matching different jQuery version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have assigned `jQuery.noConflict()` to `$jq`:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now I want to edit a jquery plugin to use $jq. There are a lot of codes in the following style:

```
(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ })(jQuery)
```

Changing `$` to `$jq` doesn't solve the problem. What should I do?

Comment: if you are trying to resolve a conflict, and all the plugins are wrapped in exectutable as you've shown, need to look eleswhere for the problem

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything. The `$` is a variable local to the function that wraps the plugin; it's immediately assigned to `jQuery`, as you can see after the function literal:

```
})(jQuery) // Immediately calls the wrapper function with jQuery being passed
           // as the $ argument.
```

Comment: I have 2 versions of jquery in the same page. If I edit nothing, it use the version that is not compatible with the plugin.

Comment: @user16948: Use `jQuery.noConflict(true)` instead of just `jQuery.noConflict()`.